# sleep() in thread causes main to sleep too

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads, sleep

I have a gateway server and 2 clients.(made in Oracle VM VirtualBox).

In my gateway server, I have listener.c listening all packets.(in a `while(1)` loop).

If the client sends a valid token, I have to put it in my authorized MACs list and all packets coming from authorized MACs must be forwarded for 180 secs. (in other words, given internet access for 180 secs).

Before 180 sec., the thing with a single user it was working.

```
/* authorized MACs list */
char *auth_macs[5];
int client;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

/* after 3 min remove the client from auth list */
void *timer(void *arg){
    sleep(180);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    auth_macs[client] = " ";
    client--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}
```

This is how I tried to implement my timer thread. `client` is a global variable that changes in main function.

```
if(has_token == 1){
    client++;
    sprintf(client_ip, "./accept.sh %s", sender);
    system(client_ip);
    auth_macs[client] = client_mac;
    /* start timer thread */
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, timer,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

This is where I start this thread. `accept.sh` is a shell script to allow forwarding.

**My problem is** I thought `sleep(180)` in timer thread was only going to stop itself. But instead, `listener.c` stops receiving packets.

How can I fix this? I want timer to wait 180 secs but still be able to receive packets in main function.

Comment: `pthread_join` will wait for the thread to terminate. However long it sleeps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep()` only suspends the calling thread. So, it doesn't affect the *main* thread.

What's problematic is the `pthread_join()` call:

```
 pthread_create(&tid, NULL, timer,NULL);
 pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

This effectively renders the multi-threading pointless. Because there's only thread that's ever going to make progress as the main thread waits until the created thread is completed.

You need to remove `pthread_join()` call and possibly it *outside* the `while(1)` loop if main thread needed to join. Alternatively, you can call `pthread_exit(0)` outside the thread creation loop so that *main* completes execution while the rest of the threads, if still alive when main thread
breaks its loop, can continue execution.

Comment: Or he could use a daemon thread instead of a normal one, so that he doesn't need to join it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The problem with that technique is that as the main thread exits it is likely to free up resources that the daemon thread is still using, causing undefined behavior in the daemon thread.  It's better to have a well-ordered shutdown sequence.